# How To Center a GridPane on a Stage

Tags: css, javafx

**Context:** I'm currently writing an application using JavaFX. At the moment I've created a login form that is placed on a Scene within a GridPane, however currently the GridPane is always aligned in the top left corner of the application.

**Problem:** What I would like to do is center the login form (within a GridPane) into the middle of the window instead of the top left. How would I go about this? Would I need to place the GridPane within another layout and center it that way? Could I somehow designate the positioning of the GridPane using CSS?

Comment: Can you post some code to show how you have things set up? I assume you have tried setting the [`alignement` property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#alignmentProperty).

Comment: This worked, thanks! Silly oversight on my part.